# Can't get different pin image using plist file

Tags: ios, xcode, image, annotations

I use plist file to store annotation data that have Name, Address, Coordinates and Icon (pin image name) strings in dictionary. I need to show my annotations on map with pin image depending on Icon string in plist. I loop my annotation dictionaries but it show on map pin image from first dict on all my pins.

My code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{


    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                    initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    for(path in dict){

        NSString *theCategory;

        theCategory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", path];
        NSLog(@"%@", path);

        NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:theCategory];

        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[anns objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"]];

    }

    pinView.canShowCallout=YES;


    return pinView;
}
```

My plist file construction:

[image]

What it show to me:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `viewForAnnotation` delegate method will get called for each annotation added.

The for-loop you have inside that method will run the same way for each annotation.  All the for-loop ends up doing (every time for each annotation) is setting `pinView.image` to the last item read by the for-loop.  This happens to be the first item in the first dictionary in the plist.

You need to instead set `pinView.image` to the `Icon` of the item that is for the ***current*** annotation that `viewForAnnotation` is being called for (ie. the `annotation` parameter that is passed).  So you *could* keep the for-loop and check if the item matches `annotation` and only then set `pinView.image` (and then `break` out of the for-loop).

But it's not a good idea to constantly be re-reading and looping through a plist in that delegate method.  It's better to make `Icon` a property of your annotation class, *set the property when creating the annotation* (you are probably looping through the plist to create the annotations in the first place), and then just use that property directly from the annotation object itself in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.

Assuming you have some custom annotation class, add Icon as a property:

```
@interface MyAnnotationClass : NSObject<MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *icon;  //<---and @synthesize it in .m
```

Then in the place where you loop through the plist to create the annotations, set the `icon` property just like you are setting the `title` property:

```
ann.title = [item objectForKey:@"Name"];
ann.icon = [item objectForKey:@"Icon"];
```

Finally, in `viewForAnnotation`, you can read the `icon` property directly from the `annotation`.  But first, you should check that `annotation` is of your custom class type (so the user location blue dot is not affected and to be reasonably sure `annotation` will have the property you're about to access):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotationClass class]])
    {
        // Note "!" sign in front of above condition.
        // Return nil (default view) if annotation is 
        // anything but your custom class.
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

    MKAnnotationView *pinView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    // Create an MKAnnotationView instead of MKPinAnnotationView
    // because we are setting a custom image.
    // Using MKPinAnnotationView sometimes overrides custom image
    // with the built-in pin view.
    if (pinView == nil)
    {
        pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else
        pinView.annotation = annotation;

    MyAnnotationClass *myAnn = (MyAnnotationClass *)annotation;
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myAnn.icon];
    // May want to check if myAnn.icon is blank (length == 0)
    // (OR if pinView.image is still nil after setting)
    // and show some default image in that case otherwise
    // annotation will be invisible.

    return pinView;
}
```

By the way, in your plist file, `Test3` has no `Icon` setting.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help! Now it working, but here: MKAnnotationView *pinView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier]; it gives me an issue (Local declaration of 'mapView' hides instance variable).

Comment: I coped with this warning, now all ok! Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you help me some more? I have about 2000 annotations and showing all on map is too slow.. how can I limit annotation view on map? Is "annotationsInMapRect" may be useful?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no built-in solution and no standard way to solve this.  One option is to dynamically add/remove annotations based on the currently displayed region (use regionDidChangeAnimated delegate method).  Another option is to implement annotation clustering (Apple gave a sample app in WWDC 2011 for this but I don't think it's publicly available).  There is some info about clustering on SO and there are also some 3rd party libraries that may help.  You could do some research or more searching based on this info and then post a more specific question.

Comment: Also note that to implement the above options, you may have to switch from a plist to a more dynamic/random-access method to store the annotation data (eg. CoreData or SQLite).  However, first I'd make sure there's nothing simple and obviously wrong with what you're doing right now before implementing a more complicated solution.  Find out exactly where the performance problem is first.